# I want to create a column that "anonymizes" the countries column for each product

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each row in my table specifies a product and country that bought it. Like this:

```
Product 1, Country A
Product 1, Country B
Product 1, Country C
Product 2, Country A
Product 2, Country B
```

I want to add another column that basically counts up each country per product. Each time starting at one for a new product.

```
    Product 1, Country A, Country 1
    Product 1, Country B, Country 2
    Product 1, Country C, Country 3
    Product 2, Country A, Country 1
    Product 2, Country B, Country 2
```

In the past this was done in a vba script simply running a loop comparing the product name with the product name from the previous row adding +1 if its the same and 1 if its not. I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this via SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([col1] varchar(9), [col2] varchar(9))
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([col1], [col2])
VALUES
    ('Product 1', 'Country A'),
    ('Product 1', 'Country B'),
    ('Product 1', 'Country C'),
    ('Product 2', 'Country A'),
    ('Product 2', 'Country B')
;
select *, concat('Country',' ',row_number() over(partition by [col1] order by [col1])) as rn_column
from #Table1
```

output

```
col1         col2       rn_column
Product 1   Country A   Country1
Product 1   Country B   Country2
Product 1   Country C   Country3
Product 2   Country A   Country1
Product 2   Country B   Country2
```

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()`

```
select *, row_number() over(partition by product order by country) as rn
from tablename
```